# Xpath with specific child and parent Classes

Tags: dom, xpath

Suppose the following HTML

```
< div class="entry" >
    < div class="partial_entry" >
    Hello
    < /div>
< /div>
```

I want to select Hello using Xpath...Select all elements with class partial_entry  where parent is of class entry..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    //div[@class='entry']/div[@class='partial_entry']/text()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug, in their DOM views("HTML" bookmark in Firebug and "Elements" bookmark in Chrome Dev Tools) you can quickly get an element xpath by righ-clicking it and selecting "copy XPath".